# How to check and replace NaN from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns.

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| apple | NaN |
| pear | NaN |
| mango | NaN |
| NaN | Strawberry |

I want to check col_2 for NaN, If the value is not NULL or NaN copy value of col_2 to col_1.

```
df = {'col_1': ['apple', 'pear', 'mango',''],
      'col_2': [Nan,Nan,Nan,'Strawberry' ]}
print(df)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
       if df.loc[idx, col_2].notna:
            print("inside if")
       else:
            print("inside else")
```

every time it goes in if and never goes in else.

Comment: Please fix your example code so that it runs. A minimal example is helpful, but the code you have provided errors out. `Nan` is not defined and `df.loc[idx, col_2].notna` calls an attribute `notna` on the value of a cell. Strings and `np.NaN` don't have this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem, which says to copy non-NaN values from col_2 to col_1. Since that's a rather unusual operation, I'm uncertain whether you meant to do that or maybe meant copy values from col1 to col2.

```
Nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['apple', 'pear', 'mango',''],
      'col_2': [Nan,Nan,Nan,'Strawberry' ]})
df.col_1.mask(df.col_2.notna(), df.col_2)
```

Comment: I fliped a negation in the answer, and it should have been `...df.col_2.notna...` in the last line of the snippet, which is now fix.

Answer (score 0):

Backfill values from `col_2` to `col_1`.

Given:

```
   col_1       col_2
0  apple         NaN
1   pear         NaN
2  mango         NaN
3    NaN  Strawberry
```

Doing:

```
df = df.bfill(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        col_1       col_2
0       apple         NaN
1        pear         NaN
2       mango         NaN
3  Strawberry  Strawberry
```

Answer (score -1):

This solved the issue.

```
df['col_2'].fillna("", inplace = True)
```

Comment: This does not copy any value from column 2 to column 1, which is what the question asks for.

Comment: This makes `nan` values into blank strings, which is the exact opposite of best practice. You should be making the blank string into a `nan`. `df = df.replace('', np.nan)`